# Trains in and out of Bangkok around Songkran

Tags: trains, thailand, bangkok

We are planning to arrive in Bangkok by train from Aranyaprathet on April 12th or 13th and leave heading for Nong Khai on the 15th or 16th night train.

I have read it is usually possible to turn up at the station in Aranyaprathet  and buy a ticket on the day of travel, but is this likely to be possible during Songkran?

Also, is it likely we will be able to get our onward tickets during our stay in Bangkok?

If not, is it possible to book tickets in advance from the UK?

Answer (score 2):

We stayed in Bangkok last summer and had a lot of problems to find long distance trains in the dates and conditions we expected (ten days in advance). So, in Songkran may be near impossible to find a train ticket if you don't book it in advance.

[There is a website](http://www.railway.co.th/home/Default.asp?lenguage=Eng) where the Thais use to book his train trips (but according to the first comment, that's not true, you can't buy train tickets online), but we just used this website to check the timetables, so I cannot give you an advice about if it works or not. Theoretically you can buy e-tickets there.

Alternatives: If you cannot find a website that allows you to book train tickets in advance, you may go to the bus station and try to buy a bus ticket when you arrive to Bangkok (ASAP) or you can try to buy short distance train tickets (sold the same day only from the station where the train starts the trip). Anyway, these options are slower and you will need more than one day to achieve your destination.

Comment: I'm Thai and I think we don't have online ticket that I know of. I would recommend the same that you should buy the ticket as soon as you arrive Bangkok, as many locals will go out of Bangkok during Songkran.